# Compiling Winmerge Sample Plugin fails on project conversion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, plugins, winmerge, project-conversion

I want to write a WinMerge Plugin to call into my C# business layer code to do a text transform.

I decided to start with the sample plugin which is closest to my own needs, but if I want to open it, Visual Studio is trying to convert its solution file but simply fails without any useful error.

The [IgnoreComments plugin source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/winmerge/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Plugins/src_VCPP/IgnoreCommentsC/) was my choosen starting point. Opening the dsp file in Visual Studio triggers the conversion.

If i start the one-way conversion a messagebox appears moments later:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Project upgrade failed.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

The migration report opens in the browser containing no more than:

```
IgnoreCommentsC.dsp: Unable to convert project. Please make sure this is a valid Visual C++ 6.0 project.
IgnoreCommentsC.dsp: Project upgrade failed.
IgnoreCommentsC.dsp: Converting project file 'C:\snip\winmerge-code-7618-trunk\Plugins\src_VCPP\IgnoreCommentsC\IgnoreCommentsC.dsp'.
```

I also opened a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/winmerge/bugs/2170/) at the project home on sourceforge over a week ago but the project is not maintained any more?!

So question is, what do I need to do to open and compile this plugin.

Comment: Opening the .dsp in VS2008 v9.0.30729.4462 QFE worked fine for me (with the can't go back upgrade warning).Compiling finds an issue with an `int j;` that needs to be moved outside of a `for` loop and a missing `fstream.h` include that can just be commented out. At that point I have something that compiles. (No intention to test it at this stage.)

Comment: I have it at that stage now as well! question is, how did you get the files from sourceforge onto your pc? I clicked the download button and loaded the latest trunk as zip file and my dsp file has unix line endings. i noticed that by accident :) i converted the dsp file to windows line endings and from there on the migration worked!

Comment: I used the Developer Version tsvn link at [Download Source Code - WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/downloads/source-code.php) to retrieve the whole source tree.